# Where am I going wrong in this Python code to create an HTML file? Am I going at all in the right direction?

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to make an HTML document with Python, but I don't even know if I'm heading in the right direction. I'm very new to both Python and my HTML experience is one course I took years ago. I couldn't find where the document was being generated until now, and I see that at some point it was actually generating a file but is no longer doing so. Can someone please look over my code and tell me what I've done wrong and what I've done right? I'll answer any questions as needed. Python 3.8.

```
def main():
inputName = str(input("Enter your name: "))
inputMajor = str(input("Enter your major: "))
inputCareer = str(input("Enter your future career and a brief description" + \
                        " of it: "))

return inputName, inputMajor, inputCareer

site = 'My Page.txt'
outfile = open(site, 'w+')

write_head()
write_body()

write_html()

outfile.close()
```

def write_html():

```
outfile.write('<html>\n')

write_head('My_Page.html')

write_body(write_html())

outfile.write('\n</html>\n')
```

def write_head():

```
outfile.write('<head>\n')

outfile.write('<title>\n' + main() + '\n</title>\n')

outfile.write('\n</head>')
```

def write_body():

```
outfile.write('<body>')
outfile.write('<center>')
outfile.write('<h1>' + inputName + '</h1>')
outfile.write('<hr />')
outfile.write('<h2>' + inputMajor + '</h2>')
outfile.write('<hr />')
outfile.write(inputCareer)
outfile.write('</center>')
outfile.write('<hr />')
outfile.write('</body>')
outfile.write('</html>')
```

main()

Answer (score 0):

Phew! There's a lot going on here, including a few calls that would end up being recursive (as in, calling themselves over and over again).

To wrap your head around the problem, try doing this all in one go as a script, no functions or anything:

```py
# Use the with statement to automatically close the file when you're done
with open('my_page.html', 'w') as f:
   f.write('<html>')
   f.write('<head>')
   f.write('</head>')
   f.write('</html>')
```

etc...

After you get this working, you can break out the write lines into individual functions as needed, so things don't get too mixed around at the outset.

Later, check out some of the other features of Python, like string formatting. That would allow you to write a string like `s = f'<h1>{my_string}</h1>'` to automatically insert the  `my_string` variable.

A function to return a header string could then look like this:

```
def insert_header(header_string):
   return f'<h1>{header_string}</h1>'
```